# !news 〇〇と入力すると、〇〇についてのニュースを出力するディスコードのボットを作ろうとしています。

Tags: python, api, websocket, discord, google-search

**以下のようなエラーが出ています。**

**エラーログ（重要部分）**

心拍数ブロックの警告:

```
[2024-02-06 11:42:46] [WARNING ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 10 seconds.
```

エラー内容:

```
File "/Users/shosukesato/ChatGPT-API/DiscordNews.py", line 35, in on_message response = await get_news(theme)
```

```
File "/Users/shosukesato/ChatGPT-API/DiscordNews.py", line 44, in get_news response = await executor.invoke({"theme": theme})
```

```
TypeError: object dict can't be used in 'await' expression
```

その他の関連情報:

```
DiscordのWebSocket接続が10秒以上ブロックされている状態。
```

```
awaitキーワードが辞書オブジェクトに適用されているためにTypeErrorが発生している。
```

```
エラーはon_messageイベントハンドラとget_news関数内で発生している。
```

以下に詳しいログの一部を載せておきます。

```
[2024-02-05 21:02:42] [WARNING ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 10 seconds.

[2024-02-05 21:02:52] [WARNING ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 20 seconds.

[2024-02-05 21:03:02] [WARNING ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 30 seconds.

[2024-02-05 21:03:08] [ERROR   ] discord.client: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shosukesato/ChatGPT-API/DiscordNews.py", line 35, in on_message
    response = await get_news(theme)
  File "/Users/shosukesato/ChatGPT-API/DiscordNews.py", line 44, in get_news
    response = await executor.invoke({"theme": theme})
TypeError: object dict can't be used in 'await' expression

[2024-02-05 21:03:09] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has successfully RESUMED session 600cafdceeb3b4cef8515252dcc7d7e7.
```

私の現在のコードは以下のようになっています。

````
import discord
from langchain.agents import initialize_agent, Tool, AgentExecutor
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.agents import AgentType, create_structured_chat_agent
from langchain_community.utilities import GoogleSearchAPIWrapper
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True  # メッセージイベントを有効にする
intents.message_content = True
intents.guilds = True    # ギルド（サーバー）関連のイベントを有効にする

CHANNEL_ID = 1234567890

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    if message.channel.id != CHANNEL_ID:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!news '):
        theme = message.content[len('!news '):].strip()
        response = await get_news(theme)
        await message.channel.send(response)

async def get_news(theme):
    llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-4", max_tokens=1500, openai_api_key='???')
    tools = define_tools()
    prompt_template = create_prompt_template(tools)
    agent = create_structured_chat_agent(llm, tools, prompt_template)  
    executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools)
    response = await executor.invoke({"theme": theme})
    return response


def create_prompt_template(tools):
    tool_names = [tool.name for tool in tools]
    agent_scratchpad = ''  # 過去のエージェントのアクションとツールの出力を保存するための変数

    # システムメッセージ
    system_message = '''Respond to the human as helpfully and accurately as possible. Your main task is to write a summary and contemplation of news based on the given theme using Google search results. Here are the tools you have access to:

    {tools}

    When using a tool, specify it by providing a JSON blob with an action key (tool name) and an action_input key (tool input). 

    Valid "action" values: "Final Answer" or {tool_names}

    Remember to provide only ONE action per $JSON_BLOB, as shown:

    ```
    {{
      "action": "$TOOL_NAME",
      "action_input": "$INPUT"
    }}
    ```

    
    Follow this format:

    Question: The given theme to research
    Thought: Consider how to find the most relevant information using the tools
    Action:
    ```
    $JSON_BLOB
    ```
    Observation: Result from the tool's execution
    ... (repeat Thought/Action/Observation until you have enough information)
    Thought: Organize the information to create a news summary and contemplation
    Action:
    ```
    {{
      "action": "Final Answer",
      "action_input": "Your news summary and contemplation in Japanese, within 1000 characters, including reference URLs at the end"
    }}

    Begin! Always respond with a valid JSON blob of a single action. Use the tools effectively to gather information and compose your response. Respond directly if appropriate. Format is Action:```$JSON_BLOB```then Observation'''

    # ヒューマンメッセージ
    human_message = '''あなたはニュース記事を書くブロガーです。
    下記のテーマについて、Google検索で最新情報を取得し、取得した情報に基づいてニュースの要約とそのニュースに関する考察を書いてください。
    1000文字以下で、日本語で出力してください。
    記事の末尾に参考にしたURLを参照元としてタイトルとURLを出力してください。
    テーマ：{theme}
    {agent_scratchpad}
    '''

    # ChatPromptTemplateの作成
    prompt_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            ("system", system_message),
            MessagesPlaceholder("chat_history", optional=True),
            ("human", human_message),
        ]
    )

    return prompt_template

# 他の関数をここに定義
def define_tools():
    search = GoogleSearchAPIWrapper(google_api_key='???', google_cse_id='???')
    return [
        Tool(
            name = "Search",
            func=lambda query: search.run(query),
            description="useful for when you need to answer questions about current events. You shoule ask targeted questions"
        ),
    ]

# Discord Botのトークンを使用して接続
client.run('???')
````